# insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables: **entitytype** and **project**. Here are the create table statements:

```
Create table project ( 
pname varchar(20) not null, 
primary key(pname)
);

create table entitytype( 
entityname varchar(20) not null, 
toppos char(100), 
leftpos char(100), 
pname varchar(20) not null, 
primary key(entityname), 
foreign key(pname) references project(pname) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

When I try to insert any values into the **entitytype** table, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "entitytype" violates foreign key constraint "entitytype_pname_fkey"
  Detail: Key (pname)=(494) is not present in table "project".
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error message means you are attempting to add an entityType that does not have a corresponding Project entry. (I don't know your domain or what you are trying to achieve, but that schema design looks wrong to me...)

Answer (score 9):

Do you not have a record in table project with a pname of (in your example) 494?

The key relationship says no pname is allowed in the entity table unless it matches a pname in the project table.

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem and I was able to solve it by removing all of the contents of the table.

Answer (score 1):

I have obtained the same issue (InnerException = {"23503: insert or update on table "table-name" violates foreign key constraint "tabename""})

This issue may arise if the table have updated version than the entry side version . because there might be a possibility of adding of additional columns in that updated version table.

- Check your entry properly.
- Check the table(package version) for all available columns.